# Charging customers monthly on specific dates

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a system where I need to charge customers monthly. The date will depend on the day they subscribe: it might be on the 1st of each month or the last day of the month.

I'm storing the first date. For example, if the customer subscribes today he will be charged on 2016-11-30, so I'm storing 2016-11-30 in the database.

When the date is a fixed value (let's say 1st) is not a problem. The problem comes when is the last day of the month. Considering the example above, that customer needs to be charged on 2016-12-31 instead of 2016-12-30 (because 31st is the last day of December).

How can I build a php script to get all customers who need to be charged on the last day of the month?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Example:

Customer A signs up today. The system says this customer needs to be charged every month on the last day of the month. There is a field in the customers table with the first date, in this case it will store 2016-11-30. That means he will be charged on 30-NOV, 31-DEC, 31-JAN, 28-FEB (or 29-FEB), 31-MAR, 30-APR and go on.

Customer B signs tomorrow. The system says that this customer needs to be charged every month on the first day of the month. The database field will store 2016-12-01. That means he will be charged on 1-DEC, 1-JAN, 1-FEB, 1-MAR, 1-APR and go on.

Now, I need to build a script which will decide when to charge customers. Customer B is not a problem, since he is set up on the 1st day of each month. But Customer A won't be charged on the same day of the month. In some months he will be charged on 30th, others 31th and in February on 28th/29th.

How can the script know that 2016-11-30 "means" in reality: "Last day of the month" rather than literally 2016-11-30?

Comment: If I signed up on `30-NOV` you would propose charging me on `31-DEC`, but if I signed up on `30-DEC` I would be charged on `30-NOV`, is that right?  If so, then there seems to be an aymmetry here.

Comment: Just to make things simple, let's assume that the system is only charging on the last day of the month. If you sign up today, you need be charged 30-NOV, 31-DEC, 31-JAN, 28-FEB (or 29-FEB), 31-MAR, 30-APR

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('last day of this month')); ?>
```

Just modify the parameters to your liking and format.
Things like last month, and next month also works.

Comment: Mmm, how can I use that in this case? The thing is: I have customers who are supposed to be charged on the 1st and customers who are supposed to be charged on the last day of the month. I'm storing the first date on the database but how can I "detect" that the stored date was the last day of that month, so I can tell: "This customer needs to be charged on the last day of the current month"?

Comment: You can modify the date parameters to only receive the day. So if you only use the 'd'. You get the 30 or 31 depending on the month.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. The problem is not to store the date. That date is already calculated and stored. The problem is, how can I know that the customer needs to be charged on the last day of the month?

Comment: what are you saving? the whole date? You can use the SUBSTRING() method to receive the records where the date (that you stored) is equal to the output of date('d', strtotime('last day of this month')); and retrieve the records that match

Comment: Yes, I'm saving the whole date. In the case of this month will be 2016-11-30. For example, date('d', strtotime('last day of this month')); today it will return 30. That's fine. But next month (December) it will return 31. If I compare the day part of 2016-11-30 (which is 30) with the result of that function (which is 31) it won't match. That means that the customer will be skipped and only charged on months with 30 days.

Comment: Thats where you can use the method SUBSTRING() in your query "SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(storedDate, 9, 2) = ?".  The output of SUBSTRING() is the date thats stored. if you also need 31 in a 30 month you can also use WHERE SUBSTRING(storedDate, 9,2) >= ?

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate? I'm not sure if I'm following you

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a [LAST_DAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_localtime) function which returns the last day of the month, of the date which is passed in.

**Example:**

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_DAY('2003-02-05');
    -> '2003-02-28'
```